# Regex - Does not starts with but contains

Tags: regex

I have created a regex to match a phone number using the following one:

**^[+0-9():.]+$**

But this regex matches a number that starts with a dot too. My usecase is to modify the above regex such that it matches a number that doesnt starts with a dot but contians a dot.

Comment: Any max digits specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this regex:

```
(^(?![.])[+0-9():.]+$)
```

You can also specify how many numbers you need in the second part of the regex

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?![.])[+0-9():.]+$
```

you can simply add a `lookahead`.